# Check if an attribute in a table has a specific value SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

I have this tables. In "Review" I want to be sure that the field "User" has the same value of the field Reservation.User (the User who made the Reservation), where Reservation has the id specified in the field Review.Id_Reservation. How could I do this?

```
CREATE TABLE Reservation
(
Reservation_Number SERIAL UNIQUE /*NOT NULL*/ PRIMARY KEY,
User VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT 'Member', FOREIGN KEY(User) REFERENCES User(Email)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE SET DEFAULT,
Place INT, FOREIGN KEY(Place) REFERENCES Place(Id_Place)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE NO ACTION,
);

CREATE TABLE Review
(
Id_Review SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
Id_Reservation INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(Id_Prenotazione) REFERENCES Reservation(Reservation_Number),
User VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Member', FOREIGN KEY(User) REFERENCES Reservation(User)
/*How can I check that this user is the same who made the reservation and not another one? */
Description TEXT,
Stars INT DEFAULT 0
Type BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE
Answer VARCHAR(64),
Private BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
CHECK(Stars > 0 AND Stars <= 5)
);
```

Comment: Just drop `user` in `review` and join `reservation` via `review.id_reservation` and take the the `user` from `reservation` if you need the user.

Comment: Is it the only way to view the User's name? In my mind I would have liked to see User's name also with a "Select * from User"

Comment: The only normalized, i.e. sane, way.

Comment: I must have a field in "Review" which assumes the value "Member" to specify who wrote the Review if the corresponding User has been deleted

Comment: Then don't delete the users, just mark them as "deleted" or "inactive" or whatever.

Comment: If a User left a review but than he decides to delete his account the review must remain, but the review must appear as wrote by "Member" instead of by the original UserName of who wrote the review

Comment: I guess the reservation changes to `'Member'` then too? Then where's the problem? Instead of the former user name you get `'Member'` from the reservation then too. You're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Sorry, you're maybe right. I'll try. Probably the only way to show the name of who wrote the Review is by making a Join with Reservation

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the referential integrity between these tables that you've already created using `Id_Reservation INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(Id_Prenotazione) REFERENCES Reservation(Reservation_Number)`
When you want to get `User` just query `Reservation` table instead of `Review`

```
Select
a.User
from
reservation a
join
review b
on a.Reservation_Number=b.Id_Reservation;
```

Comment: I must have a field in "Review" which assumes the value "Member" to specify who wrote the Review if the corresponding User has been deleted

Comment: That's not how relational databases work if you establish referential integrity. If you want to achieve what you are mentioning you'll have to insert these columns independently of each other and then write a query to see if the users are same. When you're doing this `User VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Member', FOREIGN KEY(User) REFERENCES Reservation(User)` that means there MUST be a corresponding record in `Reservation` table.